# Is it possible to calculate route with a route point in between (android)?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am able to prepare route between two points. Now i want that in addition if i want to travel via a different point in between my route, what approach i should take.

Comment: Are these two points in a straight line ?

Comment: no they are not in straight line. i want to prepare route between 3 points , like i want to go to a destination but i want to go to a place in between , so there is now depart from point , travel via point and destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. Analyze this Url :

Long Route:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=46.871716,2.361546&daddr=47.871716,2.361546+to:49.871716,2.361546

**where :**

`saddr` is the starting address

`daddr` is the midpoint

`to:` is the final destination

What you *should* be using is

> http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=46.871716,2.361546&daddr=47.871716,2.361546+to:49.871716,2.361546&sll=46.871716,2.361546&dirflg=w&hl=en&ie=UTF8&z=14&output=kml

**where :**

`sll` is the starting address

`output` gives you a kml output data

You can parse this output kml using a SAX parser to get the series of lat,lon addresses seperated by spaces with the shortest path to your destination, including your midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

How you prepare your route? I'm for this purpose use Google Web Service, you pass link to service and get *.kml file from it. This file contains points of your route wich you can draw on MapView. See example [here](http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) and descriptions of various parameters [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)

Comment: i have gone through all this before. my question is bit different. now i want to prepare route between 3 points